# How do I resolve this Flutter Installation error where the command Flutter Doctor -V states the following:

Tags: flutter, dart, installation

The output below is what I get. I have tried the nano method to add my path and other methods but I honestly have no idea what to do now. No matter what I do this error keeps rising. And I believe it may be due to case sensitivity but I do not know how to fix it still. I am hoping somebody reading this has wisdom on the issue at hand.

```
  `flutter doctor -v
    [!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
        • Flutter version 3.7.3 on channel stable at /Users/devk/desktop/flutterProjects/flutterInstallation/flutter
        ! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to /Users/devk/Desktop/flutterProjects/flutterInstallation/flutter/bin/flutter,
          which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/devk/desktop/flutterProjects/flutterInstallation/flutter.
          Consider adding /Users/devk/desktop/flutterProjects/flutterInstallation/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
        ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /Users/devk/Desktop/flutterProjects/flutterInstallation/flutter/bin/dart, which is
          not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/devk/desktop/flutterProjects/flutterInstallation/flutter. Consider
          adding /Users/devk/desktop/flutterProjects/flutterInstallation/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
        • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
        • Framework revision 9944297138 (2 days ago), 2023-02-08 15:46:04 -0800
        • Engine revision 248290d6d5
        • Dart version 2.19.2
        • DevTools version 2.20.1
        • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform
          update checks and upgrades.
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely didn't set your `ENV` path correctly.

For standard flutter installation, let's say your path to the flutter `bin` directory,  you have to add the `path` to your `.zshrc`

Open terminal

1. cd ~
2. vim `.zshrc`
3. `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/path/to/flutter/bin"`
4. Exit vim. (clicking on escape then `:wq`)

Then run `source .zshrc` to refresh